# Magnific Popup Plugin Not Showing when Previewed in Browser

Tags: magnific-popup

The code works, but for some reason the effect does not work when I open site in browser window (firefox). I did try a different browser but same thing. I am using TextWrangler to write my website. I also have Dreamweaver and I tried that too, but for some reason the plugin won't work...so then I used CodePen to see if code works and it does! Is there any tips or hints to why the plugin does not show when previewed in browser?
[Here is Magnific Popup Documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#initializing_popup)
I linked and downloaded the Magnific Popup css and js files. 
[I tried it in CodePen and it works I just changed on the image](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdQmaX#0)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gallery Test</title> 
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/magnific-popup.css"> 
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
  <script src="dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Gallery Test</h1>
<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="images/yellow-cactus.jpg" title="Yellow Cactus">
<img src="images/yellow-cactus-small.jpg">
</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }
          
    });
  
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured what I did wrong, it was a typo in my jquery library link. It didn't start off with "http:"

Simple is always the easiest things overlooked!